# Change icon througth css

Tags: css, vue.js, tree, vue-component

I used liqour-tree and need to change arrow icon with the custom one, i don't know how to do that please help!
I found that element tag where that icon is placed

```
<i class="tree-arrow expanded has-child ltr"></i>
```

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Torus456/9ko65yeb/11/

How change style on used cdn?

Comment: If you look at the documentation page of https://amsik.github.io/liquor-tree/ there is a section custom theme, here they also replase the arrow icon. The page is pointing to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amsik/qka5pxdm/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=qka5pxdm

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry for my inattention. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This element has `.tree-arrow.has-child:after` and `.tree-arrow.expanded.has-child:after`.
You have to overwrite this.

Comment: I rigth understand: I must use !important or have another way.

Comment: It is not necessary. Simple overwrite